# Are questions about tool lists or supplies for a specific project on-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

This (now closed as duplicate) [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/) asks for tool recommendations for a new 
home-owner.  However, it also provides a list of projects that the OP plans,
which made me think that the original question could be rephrased as one or more 
questions like "What tools will I need to [replace an interior door]?"

I think there's some value to be had in such questions.  For example, I've 
replaced some interior slab doors and don't recall any instructions saying that
a plunge router and template are more useful than chisel and hammer for cutting
the hinge mortises.  On the other hand, I can also see that a "what tools and/or
supplies do I need for X" question could be just one part of a "how do I do X"
question.

Should we allow these questions?  If so, should we have some guidelines in 
place for which form ("how do I" vs. "what do I need") of question is appropriate?

Full disclosure: I have a couple of such questions in mind myself.

Answer (score 7):

I think including a tools-required list in an answer to a *general how-to* question about a *specific project*  is a great idea. Having the right tool for a job can save tons of time and improve workmanship quality. I'm not so sure about the "give me a list of tools for [x] project" questions though. That might lead to a bulleted list of tools with no explanation of what to use them for, why they're necessary, etc. On the contrary, an expanded answer with steps on how to complete a project with notes on what tools to use for each phase would be very useful.

Answer (score 7):

I think asking what tools are needed for a job is fine, as long as your asking for a specific job not just "It's Christmas, what tools should I ask for?".  It could also be helpful to ask it as a separate question rather than asking "How to do job x, and what tools are required?",  asking as a separate question allows the community to better answer/vote/accept answers to the question.